# Why can't I assign anything outside a function in solidity?

Tags: function, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, decentralized-applications

I am new to blockchain development. I've recently gained a good background(or so I believe) on how the blockchain works and started working with Ethereum, as I am interested in building apps.

I started solidity recently, and **I notice that I can only assign values to variables or do any operation only inside functions in the contract. Doing any operation or assigning value outside a function gives a parsing error.** Why is that? Why do I always need to define everything strictly inside a function?
Is it related to how blockchain works? or is it that I'm using an older version of solidity? I have tried looking for answers on google, did not find anything related to this. Please let me know!

Here is the code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract dynamic_array
{
    int[] public myArray;
    int x;
    int y;

    x = x + 2;
    y = 5;
    myArray.push(1);

    function everything_works_fine_inside() public 
    {
        //these operations does not show error inside the function, but only outside
        x = x + 2; 
        y = 5;
        myArray.push(1);
    }   
   
}
```

[this is my code, just trying to figure out arrays in solidity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IMHO.png)[error msg1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfF7I.png)[error msg2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WD6Qk.png)[error msg3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeP2s.png)

Comment: Please edit your question and post the code as text (you can use markdown syntax or the `{}` button in the editor) so that answerers are able to copy the code and debug locally.

Comment: Okay, added. :)

Answer (score 1):

Solidity code is compiled into bytecode and processed by the EVM (Ethereum Virtual Machine).

There are two ways to invoke a code inside the EVM - a [transaction](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_sendtransaction) for read-write operations, and a [call](https://eth.wiki/json-rpc/API#eth_call) for read-only operations. Both of them require specifying in the `data` field **which function you want to invoke**. If you leave the `data` field empty or use an unknown value, the EVM looks for a [fallback function](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.12/contracts.html#fallback-function) in your contract. And only if it doesn't find even the fallback function, it throws an exception effectively reverting the transaction or the call.

If your goal is to invoke a snippet just once - when the contract is created - you can use a [constructor](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.12/contracts.html#constructor) as in most other OOP languages.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract dynamic_array
{
    int[] public myArray;
    int x;
    int y;

    // Constructor in version 0.4
    // is a `public` function with the same name as the contract
    function dynamic_array() public {
        x = x + 2;
        y = 5;
        myArray.push(1);
    }
}
```

---

The original issue (trying to execute code outside of a function) is not related to Solidity version. However, mind that the latest version (in March 2022) is **0.8.12**. There is no stable or LTS version yet; each new version brings new features - and more importantly security and bug fixes. For this reason you should always aim to use the latest version.

Also note that there is a difference in syntax of the constructor function between the 0.4 version that you're using, and the current 0.8 version.